# Python3: Variable Assignment, Underscore in Name produces weird Behavior in Pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

The following weird behavior I experienced in Python 3.5 using Pycharm in debug mode, but only if I `import numpy`.

There are two variables `importance` and `importance_stack`. 
When I assign the values of `importance` to `importance_stack` something weird happens. The value of `importance_stack` is not the expected `[1,1,1,1,1]` but `[[1 1 1 1 1]\n[1 1 1 1 1]\n[1 1 1 1 1]]`

```
import numpy as np
importance_stack = []
importance = [1,1,1,1,1]
importance_stack[:] = importance
```

By chance I found out, that when I rename `importace_stack` to for instance `iss` it behaves as expected, also if I do not import numpy.

```
iss=[]
importance = [1,1,1,1,1]
iss[:] = importance
```

Can somebody explain to me why that happens? Or am I messing something up in my understanding?
Thanks a lot!

edit:
- screenshot attached
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owvn1.png)

Comment: That doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the variable names. That sounds like you actually initialized `importance_stack` as a NumPy array, not an empty list.

Comment: do you mean that because of `importance_stack[:] = importance`? - would the usage of numpy arrays explain such behavior?

Comment: Could you please share some screenshots!

Comment: you are correct with your suspicion that it has to do with numpy arrays, because I had an import of np which I thought to be irrelevant, but the issue only appears with the import of numpy. Gonna add it to my post.